# Defining an array as a variable in QGIS

Tags: qgis, expression, array, qgis-variable

I want to use `array_first(@myArray)` to get the first value of `myArray` in a data defined box.
`myArray` is defined in the project variables, but I can't find the correct syntax. I tried :

- (1, 2, 'abc')
- [1, 2, 'abc']
- `array_first( array(1,2, 'abc'))` returns 1 but as soon as I define `myArray` as `array(1,2, 'abc')`, it says "can't convert into list" (translation from french).

Comment: How about setting myArray as `array(1, 2, 'abc')` then use it by `array_first(eval(@myArray))` ?

Comment: Nice. It works. I found also `array_first(string_to_array(@myArray, ','))` with `myArray` equals to `1, 2, 'abc'`.

Comment: @Kazuhito: would be nice to add this as an answer so that the question does not appear as one without a solution.

Answer (score 2):

Project variables are always stored as string (texts). So you either have to evaluate the variable with `eval()` as proposed by @Kazuhito or - probabily easier - only enter the array's **elements** (not the array itself) as content of the variable and create the array where you need it. So the content of the project variable `my_array` = `1, 2, 'abc'`

Then convert the string to an array and get the first element with `[0]` to access the element no. 0 of the array: counting of elements starts with 0, so you get the first element. So its the same as `array_first()`, but shorter:

```
string_to_array (@my_array)[0]
```